# value error in combining csvs using python

Tags: python, pandas

Python Newbie here, First time poster:

Attempting to combine csvs. I have put all the files in one folder. Attempting to combine them into 1 csv.

```
from os import chdir
from glob import glob
import pandas as pdlib

# Produce a single CSV after combining all files
def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
   # Consolidate all CSV files into one object
   result_obj = pdlib.concat([pdlib.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files])
   # Convert the above object into a csv file and export
   result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding="utf-8")

# Move to the path that holds our CSV files
csv_file_path = 'C:/GolfPython/'
chdir(csv_file_path)
print(csv_file_path)
# List all CSV files in the working dir
file_pattern = ".csv"
list_of_files = [file for file in glob('*.{}'.format(file_pattern))]
print(list_of_files)

file_out = "ConsolidateOutput.csv"
produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)`
```

Used code I found online.

Received the following error: **
  File "C:\Users\dsitar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 262, in **init**
    raise ValueError('No objects to concatenate')

ValueError: No objects to concatenate**

Answer (score 1):

You are using file_pattern = ".csv" and then putting another dot(.) in glob('*.{}'.format(file_pattern))

So, your program is searching for files with format ..csv which obviously don't exist.

To fix it, you can do one of the following

1.) Change file_pattern to "csv" (without dot) OR
2.) Change string formatting to '*{}'.format(file_pattern)'  (No Dot in string)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
list_of_files = [file for file in glob('*.{}'.format(file_pattern))]
```

Needs to be:

```
list_of_files = [file for file in glob('*{}'.format(file_pattern))]
```